# is null in where clause with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I searched in stackoverflow i couldn't get my answer . any one help me for this requirement.

```
  declare @val varchar(800)
  set @val='current data'
select * from [FeatureCal_GrowthPlan] where snapshot_dt= case when @val='current data' then '2017-01-01'  else  @val end
```

the above query is working fine. But my requirement is similar to below

```
declare @val varchar(800)
 set @val='current data'
select * from [FeatureCal_GrowthPlan] where snapshot_dt= case when @val='current data' then is null  else  @val end
```

I would like to select all null values when @val='current data' is true else select respective date which variable @val have.

any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: try `null` instead of `is null`

Comment: there is difference between snapshot_dt=null and snapshot_dt is null. Am I right

Comment: You are right. NULL stands for the unknown value. Hence `snapshot_dt = null` can only result in "unknown", for we don't know whether the unknown value might match the other value or not. `snapshot_dt = null` will never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by using below query, guys correct me if I am wrong so it will useful to someone.

```
     declare @val varchar(800)
 set @val='current data'
select * from [FeatureCal_GrowthPlan] where  isnull(snapshot_dt,'1900-01-01')= case when @val='current data' then '1900-01-01'  else   @val end
```

Comment: If you have an index on the snapshot_dt column. Because of the operation on column (ISNULL), this approach prevents using index appropriately. If you have too many rows I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: This is a common approach. It assumes no `snapshot_dt` value is `1900-01-01`. Because of that, while it may work for your specific use case, in general, it cannot work as an answer to the question you actually asked. But if you describe this limitation in your answer, the answer is still likely to be useful to others. Aside from that, @sarslan's comment is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
declare @val varchar(800)
 set @val='current data'
select * from [FeatureCal_GrowthPlan] where 
    ( @val='current data' AND snapshot_dt is null )
    OR 
    ( @val <> 'current data' AND snapshot_dt = @val )
```

Comment: good approach, when I tried the above query I got the error as "onversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." we can overcome by using convert varchar method.